# MS Acess Macro to Record number of rows affected by Each Queries

Tags: ms-access

I am running series of access queries to update couple of the tables and upon running each queries, i get message pop up saying number of rows going to be affected.  Is there a way using macro to record the number of rows affected into a table or even record to excel sheet?

Below is the code I created based on your feedback.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub GenerateReports()

Dim strSQL1 As Object
Dim strSQL2 As Object


DoCmd.SetWarnings False

'First run the SELECT query to find out how many rows are effected

Set strSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM Count_Number_of_Rows WHERE Field1 = 'query1'"
Set rec1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL1)

rec1.MoveFirst
rec1.MoveLast
MyRecNums = rec1.RecordCount

'Some code to write MyRecNums to a table
'Blah blah

'Now run the actual Update query

CurrentDb.Execute "query1", dbFailOnError

Set strSQL2 = "UPDATE Count Number of Rows SET Field2 = 'query2' WHERE Field1 = 'query1'"
DoCmd.ExecuteSQL strSQL2


DoCmd.SetWarnings True


End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're willing to use VBA instead of a macro, look up `RecordsAffected` property in Access' help system.

Comment: Thank you. I will look it up there also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long way (and only way I can think of) would be to mirror each Update query with a Select query.

```
'First run the SELECT query to find out how many rows are effected
Set strSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyField = 'SomeValue'"
Set rec1 = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(strSQL1)

rec1.MoveFirst
rec1.MoveLast
MyRecNums = rec1.RecordCount

'Some code to write MyRecNums to a table
'Blah blah

'Now run the actual Update query
Set strSQL2 = "UPDATE MyTable SET MyField2 = 'Whatever' WHERE MyField = 'SomeValue'"
DoCmd.ExecuteSQL strSQL2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  But I do not understand how to implement this because I am a newbie to Access.  Let say MyTable name is 'Dummy_table'.  How does the complete statement look like?

Comment: And what is 'MyField' and 'SomeValue' ?

Comment: Just change the table names in my code to "Dummy_table".  "MyField" is the name of your field that you're filtering on, and "SomeValue" is the value of the field you're filtering.  Basically, all you need to do is replace your table name, field name and value in the code above with whatever your actual table name, field name and values are.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. is strSQL1 and strSQL2 should be defined as what? when i defined them as object, it says 'type mismatch'.

Comment: I just inserted my codes based on your feedback. Can you take a look and let me know? Thank you